# register user in legacy database table

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and would like to know if I would have to register a user in a table that I created in my database, or in the future I could register a table "Product" or "HelpDesk"

My project is HelpDesk.
My app is Login.

**login\view.py**

```
from .forms import Testecadastro

def cadastro(request):
form = Testecadastro(request.POST or None)
if request.method == 'POST':
        form.save()
return render(request, 'cad.html', {'form': form})
```

**login\forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Testecadastro

class TesteCadastro(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Testecadastro
    fields = ['username', 'password']
    widgets = {
        'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'maxlength': 255}),
        'password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'maxlengeth': 255})
    }
```

**login\model.py**

```
class Testecadastro(models.Model):
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
username = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
password = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = True
    db_table = 'Testecadastro'
```

**login\url.py**

```
from .views import cadastro
from .views import user_login
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
path('teste/', cadastro, name='cadastro'),
path('login/', user_login, name='login')
```

**url.py**

```
app_name = 'helpdesk'
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('teste/', include(login_urls)),
path('login/', include(login_urls))
```

**login\templates\cad.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <form  method="post" class="form-signin">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login</h2>
        <label>Usuário:</label>
        {{ form.username }}
        {{ form.username.errors }}
        <label>Password:</label>
        {{ form.password }}
        {{ form.password.errors }}
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" 
type="submit">Entrar</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**Traceback**

```
    Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
D:\AlfaHelpDesk\venvHelpDesk\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) ...
▶ Local vars
D:\AlfaHelpDesk\venvHelpDesk\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) ...
▶ Local vars
D:\AlfaHelpDesk\venvHelpDesk\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
D:\AlfaHelpDesk\HelpDesk\login\views.py in cadastro
            form.save() ...
▶ Local vars
D:\AlfaHelpDesk\venvHelpDesk\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py in save
                       force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields) ...
▶ Local vars
D:\AlfaHelpDesk\venvHelpDesk\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py in save_base
            updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields) ...
▶ Local vars
D:\AlfaHelpDesk\venvHelpDesk\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py in _save_table
                                      forced_update) ...
▶ Local vars
D:\AlfaHelpDesk\venvHelpDesk\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py in _do_update
        filtered = base_qs.filter(pk=pk_val) ...
▶ Local vars
D:\AlfaHelpDesk\venvHelpDesk\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in filter
        return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
D:\AlfaHelpDesk\venvHelpDesk\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in _filter_or_exclude
            clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs)) ...
▶ Local vars
D:\AlfaHelpDesk\venvHelpDesk\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py in add_q
        clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases) ...
▶ Local vars
D:\AlfaHelpDesk\venvHelpDesk\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py in _add_q
                    split_subq=split_subq, ...
▶ Local vars
D:\AlfaHelpDesk\venvHelpDesk\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py in build_filter
        condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value) ...
▶ Local vars
D:\AlfaHelpDesk\venvHelpDesk\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py in build_lookup
        lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs) ...
▶ Local vars
D:\AlfaHelpDesk\venvHelpDesk\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py in __init__
        self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup() ...
▶ Local vars
D:\AlfaHelpDesk\venvHelpDesk\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py in get_prep_lookup
            return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs) ...
▶ Local vars
D:\AlfaHelpDesk\venvHelpDesk\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py in get_prep_value
        return int(value) ...
▶ Local vars
```

Error: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'QueryDict'

Comment: show all traceback

Comment: Show urls.py,faz favor.

Comment: Done! something missing?

Comment: full traceback is missing!

Comment: Sorry man, Done.